# How to get demographics(Age, Gender) of people who downloaded the application

Tags: android, google-play

I have deployed an application on Play Store. I need to get the `Age` and `Gender` of people who downloaded the application. Is it possible to get these attributes, or do I need to implement Google Analytics to get these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not even possible with Google Analytics. You need to ask users about their gender and age.

Comment: In Google Analytics i can see this
`Your Demographics and Interest Reports have been enabled, but your Analytics tracking code does not include the necessary support to show them`

Comment: @Kirmani88 hm, probably `Demographics` is based on some Google account data. Then user still need to give you access to his/her account. Here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en `Android Advertising ID` is mentioned. Probably you need to read more about `Advertising ID` https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en